# BaseCustomLayer draw is not hit

Tags: arcobjects

I create an object derived from BaseCustomLayer which draws a polyline.
I call Map.addLayer(myBaseCustomLayer) and the function

```
public override void Draw(esriDrawPhase drawPhase, IDisplay Display, ITrackCancel trackCancel)
```

is hit.  BUT if I set DynamicMapEnabled = true the draw function is not hit !

Any hints would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Here's my understanding, based on this illustration from [the documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/How_dynamic_display_works/0001000003wt000000/):

When the map is put into dynamic mode, a background image is created.  Any "non dynamic" layers (those that don't implement IDynamicLayer) are drawn to a cache and used as a background image.  OpenGL is used to quickly draw display lists on top of this background image.  Therefore, I would only expect ILayer.Draw for a custom layer to be called once - when the dynamicdisplay mode starts.

Comment: Let's say you wanted to draw a triangle to the map and then have something move around the screen, what's the correct way to do this?  

I turned off dynamic, drew a basicLayer which drew a polyline -> turned on dynamic -> and then drew a glyph but my line disappeared.

It looks like I need to create my own custom Raster layer and have that turn into the background layer... And I guess BaseCustomLayer must not be a raster layer then... ?